# As an European citizen, what do I need to get remote work in the US?

Tags: united-states, contracts, telecommute

As title says. I don't want to move, just to get a remote position. Do I need any permits? Or just a company that is contracted by the US one?

Comment: I don't know enough detail to put a full answer, but I believe the company can only use you if you have all the permits you'd need to work on-shore.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: let's say I'm self-employed in a European company and that's contracted by the US one.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I seem to remember If you work directly for a US company, but are offshore, you need to have the same permits/permissions as a US worker.  Of course working for a company working for a US company may be different.  I was looking at the legalities of jobs which allowed remote workers on jobs.stackexchange.  The OP was asking about being in Europe and working for a US company, not working for a company working for a US company

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are self-employed as a European company (or employed by a European company), my understanding is that you don't need any US permits to get remote work.

My companies (current and past) have often outsourced work to offshore companies with cheaper labor costs. US work permits were not required for those workers, since they never worked directly for the US companies, and never worked in the US. We did bring them in for some training, and it was necessary to limit their time in the US, and to make sure they only trained and didn't actually work.

Good luck.